# Why are css transitions with hover not working?

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

My code goes something like this

```
#padmeni {
    width:140px;
    display:none;
    background-color:#5F9EA0;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:160px;
    display:none;
    border-radius:2px; 
    opacity:0.9;
    padding-top:10px;
    -webkit-transition: display 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: display 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: display 1s ease-in;
    transition: display 1s ease-in;
}

nav ul li:hover #padmeni {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Not everyone's first language is English. Things like `smth` and `u` are bad. Use full words.

Answer (score 0):

Only [animatable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) can be transitioned. `display` is not one of them.

There are no mid-points to transition though.